error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService after updating firebase-messaging-unity
I am upgrading the dependencies in an Android archive that I use in a Unity game client, and one is giving me trouble. When upgrading from firebase-messaging-unity 8.5.0 to 11.5.0 I started getting an error in Android Studio saying that MessageForwardingService is not defined.
The way it's being used is basically identical to the code example in the Firebase docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client
Was this removed, or do I need to include another dependency? I have also tried version 12.2.0 of the Unity module, but I get the same result.
After updating the firebase-messaging-unity module I would have expected the API interface to remain the same, or for the documentation to reflect the need to update our code. The only difference between a working build and build errors is the use of firebase-message-unity 8.5.0 and 11.5.0 (or 12.2.0).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
